# Attachment Param Only Passing Name of File - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, attachment, nested-forms

I'm trying to pass a document in a nested form in Rails 4, but the params are only taking the attachment name. I've done some looking and most of the problems people were experiencing were because they left out `:multipart => true` which I have in my code. I have two `fields_for` in the same form (i.e. two child forms) I'm not sure if this could be part of the issue.

Here's my form. I'm leaving out some attributes, divs, and the error message for the sake of brevity

```
    = form_for([@auction, @bid], html: {class: ''})do |f|
      = f.fields_for :inventory_part, InventoryPart.new do |cm|
        .form-group
          .col-lg-6
            %label.col-lg-4.control-label Part No.
              = cm.text_field :part_num
            %label.col-lg-4.control-label Manufacturer
              = cm.text_field :manufacturer
        .form-group
            %label Serial No.
              = cm.text_field :serial_num
            %label Condition
              .inv-radio-btns
                .right-radios
                  .radio
                    = cm.radio_button :condition, "recent"
                    = cm.label :condition, "NE"
                  .radio
                    = cm.radio_button :condition, "overhaul"
                    = cm.label :condition, "OH"
                  .radio
                    = cm.radio_button :condition, "as_removed"
                    = cm.label :condition, "AR"

          .form-group
            %label Amount:
              = f.text_field :part_price
          .form-group
            %label Shipping Est:
              = f.text_field :est_shipping_cost
          .form-group
              %label Documentation:
              = f.fields_for :document, Document.new, html: { :multipart => true, class: "form-control"} do |dm|
                  .files
                    %label.btne
                      Browse
                      = dm.file_field :attachment

        = f.submit 'Submit Quote', class: 'btn btn-defualt bg-success pull-right'
```

as requested, the controller action:

```
def temp_user_create_bid
        Bid.strip_symbols(bid_params)
        @bid = @auction.bids.new(bid_params)
        @inventory_part = InventoryPart.new(inventory_part_params)
        part_match = Part.find_by(part_num: @inventory_part.part_num.upcase)
        respond_to do |format|
            if part_match
                @bid.inventory_part = @inventory_part
                if @bid.save
                    @inventory_part.add_part_details(part_match, current_user)
                    if @inventory_part.save
                        document_params[:attachment].each { |doc| @bid.documents.create(name: doc.original_filename, attachment: doc)} if document_params
                        Notification.notify_other_bidders(@auction, current_user, "A quote has been placed on an RFQ you are participating in!")
                        Notification.notify_auctioner(@auction, "A new quote was placed in your RFQ!")
                        format.html { redirect_to @bid.auction, notice: 'Your quote has been saved' }
                    else
                        format.html { render :temp_user_new_bid }
                    end
                elsif !part_match
                    flash[:error] = "Part number is not valid"
                    format.html { redirect_to temp_user_new_bid(@bid.auction), alert: 'Part Number was not valid.' }
                else
                    flash[:error] = @bid.errors.full_messages.to_sentence.gsub('.','')
                    format.html { redirect_to new_auction_bid_path(@auction) }
                    format.json { render json: @bid.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
                end
            end
        end
    end
```

and the params

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"wKAxNdL0rRdN5iHUMHEw7lBl6gkdWK+MDddlWUsGIYdXVkcTMvT/hNt0/45Y6SYxXf0A8p5LY/6IsiK68Jtj2A==", 
"bid"=>{
  "inventory_part"=>{
    "part_num"=>"123", "manufacturer"=>"Textron", 
    "serial_num"=>"2342", "condition"=>"overhaul"
  }, 
  "part_price"=>"2344.44", "est_shipping_cost"=>"203.00", 
  "quantity"=>"1", "tag_date"=>"2017-05-23", "reference_num"=>"34ko33", 
  "document"=>{
    "attachment"=>"Second EIN.pdf"
  }
}, 
"commit"=>"Submit Quote", "controller"=>"bids",
"action"=>"temp_user_create_bid", "auction_id"=>"113"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use `file_field_tag` instead of `file_field` and check if it works.

Comment: It still only passes the name of the file as the `:attachment`

Comment: The controller action isn't pretty, it's new and I haven't refactored.. but there it is

Comment: I added the params as well

Answer (score 1):

> I've done some looking and most of the problems people were
>   experiencing were because they left out :multipart => true which I
>   have in my code.

You have it in your code, but in the *wrong place*. You should pass `:multipart => true` as a *html option* for `form_for` *not* `fields_for` to accept attachments.

```
= form_for([@auction, @bid], html: {:multipart => true, class: ''}) do |f|
```

and remove it from the `fields_for`

```
= f.fields_for :document, Document.new, html: {class: "form-control"} do |dm|
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this change doesn't fix my issue. Only the name of the file is still being passed, as the "attachment"